# Why is CSS pixel width of 500px measure 612 using ruler?

Tags: css

I have a CSS div set to 500 width.

Yet when I display the page on a 1600x900 monitor (laptop) and use the ruler from F12 Dev tools, it shows the width at 612px.  It shows even larger on my 27" monitor.

Is there something I am missing? I thought the pixels of CSS were actual pixel size on the screen.

```
.test
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

There is no other CSS.  You can see the test page at [test site](http://js1.biz) It's just one large blue square 500 by 500.

*The answer*

I did a reset of IE settings and checked the site again.  Now the blue box showed the correct size - There is a View setting that was set to 125%.  When set to 100%, the CSS size is perfectly correct.

Greg

Comment: You are going to need to provide relevant HTML/CSS to replicate this - it could be a number of things. I bet there is a `%` based padding set within the `div`. Thus causing it so expand beyond `960px`..

Comment: Share the CSS so that we can help.

Comment: OK, added a link to the site so you can see it directly.

Comment: That class has `width:900px` set (not 960, as you said) – and that’s also how wide the element is (plus the `padding-right` of `100px` it gets from `.sign-up`) according to the layout panel in my DOM inspector (in Chrome and Opera).

Comment: OK, to simplify, I changed the page at the link above so it is a single page with a blue square set to 500x500 pixles.  And in the Layout tab of F12, it shows the size to be 500x500.  But measuring with the F12 ruler tool which shows ACTUAL pixels, it shows it to be 612!

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about but this square is exactly 500px wide and 500px high. And it doesn't really help if you say F12 Dev tools if we don't even know your browser.

Comment: It shows as a perfect 500 x 500 on my screen, and I even screen-shotted it and checked it in a graphics editor.

Comment: @Layne, I am using IE 10.  It has a tool in it called Ruler which you use to click and drag across the scree and it will measure the number of pixels.  When I use it to measure the full width of my laptop, it shows the expected 1600 pixels.  When I use it to measure the aforementioned blue box, it shows it to be 612px.  I don't know what's up with this.

Comment: @Graham, OK, thanks for checking that.  It's not really that important.  I was just trying to use the F12 ruler to measure something on the screen and the results were off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser view was set to 125%.